# Occasional Script Task error in SSIS

Tags: vb.net, ssis, buffer

I am going through a very peculiar situation while executing a package. The derived columns in all the DFTs in the package have been replaced with Script tasks due to a business requirement.

Executing the package on development resulted in an occasional error sometimes with the error statement as '**Value is too large to be added to the buffer**' and sometimes the script task failed stating

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters
>   describe an un-representable DateTime

OR

> The milliseconds value is out of bounds (not between 0 & 999).

Some other error messages received during the executions are stated below:-

> Description: Unspecified error  End Error  Error: 2016-11-24
>   10:51:03.37     Code: 0xC0047062     Source: Dft_x  [279]
>   Description: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day
>   parameters describe an un-representable DateTime. at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception
>   e)     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32
>   inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProcessInput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
>   wrapper, Int32 inputID, IDTSBuffer100 pDTSBuffer, IntPtr
>   bufferWirePacket)  End Error Error:

&

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
>   PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source 1 returned error code
>   0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline
>   engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is
>   defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline
>   stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.
>
> [OleDst_Pricing [165]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An
>   OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid date format".
>   [OleDst_xyz [165]] Error: There was an error with
>   OleDst_xyz.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[DateColumn] on
>   OleDst_xyz.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status
>   returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the
>   specified type.". [OleDst_x [165]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OleDst_xyz.Inputs[OLE
>   DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907A occurred,
>   and the error row disposition on "OleDst_xyz.Inputs[OLE DB
>   Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on
>   the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [FltSrc_x 1 [313]] Error: The attempt to add a row to the
>   Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
>   PrimeOutput method on FltSrc_BR_x 1 returned error code
>   0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline
>   engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is
>   defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline
>   stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.

However after tweaking the *DefaultMaxBufferRows & DefaultMaxBufferSize property*, I successfully executed the package individually and through SQL Server about 40 times on Development and Test environment to make sure it doesn't fail again. But the Production execution again failed with similar date specific error.

I am posting the code below contained in the Script Tasks which is similar in each of the DFTs:-

```
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent
    Dim xyzArray() As String
    Dim rowValue As String
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim columnxyz As String '= Me.Variables.MaterialMaster.ToString()
    'Dim v1 As IDTSVariables100


Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

    rowValue = Row.XYZtoABC.ToString() + "~".ToString()
    xyzArray = rowValue.Split(New Char() {"~"c})
    strDate = Row.DateColumn.ToString()
    columnxyz = Row.columnxyz.ToString()
    CreateNewOutputRows()

End Sub

Public Sub CreateNewOutputRows()

    ResultBuffer.AddRow()
    ResultBuffer.xyz1 = xyzArray(1)
    ResultBuffer.xyz2 = xyzArray(2)
    ResultBuffer.xyz3 = xyzArray(3)
    ResultBuffer.xyz4 = xyzArray(4)
    ResultBuffer.xyz5 = xyzArray(5)


    ResultBuffer.Datecolumn = CDate(strDate)
    ResultBuffer.columnxyz = columnxyz

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is data related.   You are occasionally importing data that cannot be represented as a date, and trying to output it as a date.   Since you don't have any code in place to catch this, you are getting an error.

You could put this line in a TRY .. CATCH block, and decide what to do in the cases where the string cannot be converted to a date:

```
   ResultBuffer.Datecolumn = CDate(strDate)
```

Comment: For the Date Column the input is being supplied through GETDATE() using a derived column before this task.

Comment: Then maybe it's a different column, but the general point of the answer is still correct.   It's data-related, and you are occasionally trying to stuff a value into a data-type that cannot hold it.  One solution is to use TRY..CATCH to handle the error when it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If `strDate` has a specific format (i.e.: `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"`). you have to use `Date.ParseExact()` function like the following:

```
ResultBuffer.Datecolumn = Date.ParseExact(strDate,"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Also if you have many specific formats, you can declare a string array and pass it to this function like the following:

```
dim strFormats() as string = {"dd-MM-yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd"}
ResultBuffer.Datecolumn = Date.ParseExact(strDate,strFormats,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```

`CDate` function is related to your regional settings so it is best practice to work with `Date.ParseExact`

Another point is to use `DB_TIMESTAMP` as column type instead of `DT_DATE`

Comment: strDate is getting input from GETDATE() through a derived column before the script task. Would it still be required to use Date.ParseExact()?

Comment: @MominGoni `GETDATE()` is depending on SQL Server collation, `CDATE()` is depending on machine regional settings

Comment: @MominGoni try to use column type `DB_TIMESTAMP` instead of `DT_DATE`